# Javascript .open opens maximized in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, window.open

When using the below to open a new window in Chrome the window always opens maximized. In Firefox it opens at the correct 200x200 size, so how can I get Chrome to behave the same and not maximize?

```
gamewindow = window.open("","","width=200,height=200");
```

I'm now finding that if I include location=0 and menubar=0 that they still show up in both Firefox and Chrome. What's the deal with this? Is there some other way to do pop out windows because it seems window.open is unreliable.

Comment: What values are you actually using in the first two parameters? Empty strings may not play well in all browsers; you should at least be providing a target.

Comment: I do have an actual URL and name in the first two parameters, but I was under the impression that those could both be left blank anyway. The first going to an about:blank page and the second one just being a blank name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm testing your example on win7 and it works fine on chrome, at least for me

Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D6Y27/)

Are you using it on a maximized (fullscreen) window on Mac?

Btw, I would not recommend using  `window.open` since it usually gets blocked by pop-up blocker

**Edit:** tested on Chrome stable, build 28.0.1500.95 m

Comment: I'm running Chrome 29.0.1547.57 m on Windows 7 and in your fiddle the pop up is opened maximized no matter what. Could you point me in the direction of other methods to handle popup windows?

Comment: Mmm...I've just updated chrome to v29 and my fiddle still work - maybe you have some configuration/plugin interfering?
It depends on what you're trying to accomplish, but you can try with something like [this](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal), if a modal window inside the current one is enough for your task :)

Comment: It seems to be just my chrome as I had a friend test my full app and she said it didn't open maximized. I need full popups in a new window so I guess I'll just stick with this. This isn't the first time where chrome will do something weird while any other chrome of the same version on another computer does differently.